# Can a computer run a localhost (MAMP etc) as a backup for if internet is not available - and update server database?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I have been looking into creating a custom mySQL Point Of Sales system so that there is one centralised database for inventory levels between multiple stores and online etc.

The biggest problem I see is the unlikely event that the internet drops out in the bricks and mortar stores. If this were to happen, could it be set up so that the POS system is running off a local mySQL database on that computer (using MAMP or something similar) and then once internet is available again, automatically sync the databases to update sales and inventory levels?

In regards to 'how is the actual POS system going to be accessed without internet' I'm was thinking that the POS system would be run on the server when internet is available, and then when the net drops out it would be run from files stores on the machine pointing to the local database on the machine.

Comment: If you have control over the browsers in use, your best bet might be to look into [HTML5 Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).  Otherwise, consider [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL Master/Slave Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html) would seem the logical approach.

Your MAMP code works directly against the local (slave) database; and when the MAMP server has access to the master database, the databases stay synchronised. If the slave loses access to the Internet, it's still working locally; and when the internet connection is restored it will synchronise again with the master.

With a little care in the database design (particularly autoincrement pks), you can run multiple local/slave servers all with their own local store data, and the master is a repository of data across all stores.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a minimal & viable solution would just be to have all of the POS data entered locally as well as on the remote database, then it serves as a sort of backup in case anything happens to the central DB.

As far as automating the 'fix' of the central DB after an outage, maybe the best way is to have the central system request sales data from the local DBs of each store. If the workflow is setup like this, then you don't really have to do anything 'special' about internet outages.

Comment: A like the "write locally, backup later" approach. It's a general approach rather than specific to the problem. It may however be clunky if you want instant updates of the central db in the common case, but that can be solved by very tight syncing or something.

Comment: Good point Emil! Hadn't really considered update speed as a factor, I think of POS as a slow-sync system. It would be pretty cool to watch some real-time sales graphs across multiple stores, though!

Comment: Yes, and some companies also like to track stock status in real-time (for example to show customers a live status on their website, or to allow the staff to tell customers where they can go to buy things that are sold out in the current store).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is obviously writes. You can use replication to always have a local *readable* copy of the database, but it's tricky to have multiple masters when using replication. I haven't used MySQL Cluster, but it may be what you need.

But since the problem is writes you can possibly implement the writing part of the POS system as a service you send messages to. When the network is down, queue the messages and send them when online.

An easier solution may actually be to always ensure network stability. Set up some mobile (GSM/3G) connection for failover and possibly even a standard POTS telephone line as well.